# Parallel processing cluster not used when running dredge on a MCMCglmm model with the parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mumin

I am using `MCMCglmm` to run a PGLMM model. Since the aim is not to make predictions, I'm using `dredge` (from MuMIn) to calculate model-weighted parameter values and confidence intervals. Due to the large number of fixed effects, I thought it would be a good idea to implement a parallel processing workflow so that it doesn't take a day or two. I am using fully-updated Win10 and R Studio 2021.09.2.

The model and model selection code for reference:

```
 fullmod<-upd.MCMCglmm(occ~den*month+year+diet+dssi+eu_trend+hssi*migration+mass+latitude,
                random=~phylo+spp,family="gaussian",ginverse=list(phylo=inv.mat),prior=prior,
               data=merged_full,nitt=nitt,burnin=burnin,thin=thin, verbose=F)
all_mods <- dredge(fullmod, trace=2)
```

This model works perfectly, and using `dredge` without a cluser also runs with no issues, so I know the issue lies solely in my implementation of parallel processing. [According to the relevant documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/MuMIn/man/pdredge.html), `pdredge` is depreciated and so dredge can be used directly; I tried `pdredge` regardless [based on the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497297/dredge-on-gam-returns-na-results-for-loglik-aicc-delta-and-weight) and I get the exact same error.

Clustering code:

```
    library(parallel)
    library(snow)
    
    # Detect number of cores and create cluster (leave one out to not overwhelm pc)
    nCores <- detectCores() - 1
    cl <- makeCluster(nCores, type = "SOCK")
    
    
    # Export all objects to be used to all the cores in the cluster
    clusterExport(cl, list("merged_full","inv.mat","prior","nitt","burnin","thin","fullmod",
"upd.MCMCglmm"))
    
    # Load packages to be used
    clusterEvalQ(cl,library(MuMIn,logical.return =T))
    clusterEvalQ(cl,library(MCMCglmm,logical.return =T))
    
    fullmod<-upd.MCMCglmm(occ~den*month+year+diet+dssi+eu_trend+hssi*migration+mass+latitude,random=~phylo+spp,
                                                 family="gaussian",ginverse=list(phylo=inv.mat),prior=prior,
                                                 data=merged_full,nitt=nitt,burnin=burnin,thin=thin, verbose=F)
    all_mods <- MuMIn::dredge(fullmod, trace=2, cluster=cl)
```

And the output:

```
> all_mods <- MuMIn::dredge(fullmod, trace=2, cluster=cl)
Not using cluster.
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
```

And of course, the code runs fine, just without clustering. Checking the Task Manager, I can see that the cluster is up and running, it's just that the other cores are not being used.

I did not provide a reproducible example as the model runs with no issues , but I can do so if required. Anyone knows what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the `MuMIn` package, and the fix is as simple as just renaming your cluster to anything else but `cl`. I spent an extremely frustrated day trying to figure out this issue and wound up digging around in the code for `dredge.R` on Github and found this:

[image: screenshot of dredge.R]

When I ran `isTRUE(evaluate) && inherits(cl, "cluster")` on my `cl` object, it kept returning `TRUE`! So obviously my cluster was successfully created and passing the tests in `dredge`. However, I thought that perhaps `cl <- match.call()` (line 31) was potentially messing up the dredge function using my own `cl` object. Renaming my cluster to `clu` fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks a million, that fixed it for me too! It will never stop being amazing/frustrating how simple the solution is sometimes.

Comment: This saved me today! I never would have guessed. Thanks!